# Missing Events in Kibana due to roll out of events from .json file

Tags: json, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I'm using ELK, due to so much of logging happening, the events in .json file is rolling out to .json.1 file so, when I run my test, I am not getting all the events in kibana ( for ex, if I am having 1200 events, I will get 1100 events entries in kibana, and rest 100 will be rolled out to .json.1, once .json file is filled completely. But I have made a configuration in logstash  to read only .json file and I am missing all 100 events present in .json.1.). How to get those rolled out 100 events in kibana?

Answer (score 1):

It seems your basic problem is too many events logged to file and logstash is not picking them up fast enough.

How are the events generated? Can you change the logger to log to rabbitmq or redis or something else? Then you can have logstash pickup these messages from rabbitmq or something else.

This approach will give you higher guarantee of delivery and lower risk of losing messages.

Comment: On the other hand, if RabbitMQ is down or the logging application for some other reason can't publish log messages, the application either blocks or you won't get any logs. Logging straight to a broker can be useful but should be done with caution.

Answer (score 0):

While it depends a bit on how the files are rotated, it should be fine to just list both files foo.json and foo.json.1 in the filename patterns that Logstash watches. Or, increase the interval between rotations.

Either way it requires that what you're describing only happens during rare bursts and that the overall rate of logging is significantly lower than what Logstash can process. If not you simply have to increase Logstash's performance.

Comment: How to increase the interval between rotations? Is there a way to do it?

Comment: I'm sure there is, but exactly how it can be done depends on who's responsible for the rotation. Chances are it's logrotate, in which case there's probably a config file in /etc/logrotate.d.